# Can't get 3 divs to float side by side

Tags: html, css

I'd like to get my 3 divs side by side. The 2nd div (the middle one) would be at 10% so there is space between the left and right div. I set my left and right divs to be at 45%. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/sukcv46p/22/

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper-segmentation">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
    <div class="wrapper-promo">
        <div class="title-top">
            <h2 class="block-title">
                Three states or less</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="promo-content">
            <p>Bid and RFP Notification Only</p>
        <p>Online and email support</p>
            <p><img height="31" src="http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/button_get_started_orange.png" width="112" /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="centercolumn">
        Center
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">
    <div class="wrapper-promo">
        <div class="title-top">
            <h2 class="block-title">
                National or Regional</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="promo-content">
            <p>Bid and RFP Notification Only</p>
        <p>Online and email support</p>
            <p><img height="31" src="http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/button_get_started_orange.png" width="112" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#wrapper-segmentation {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftcolumn, #rightcolumn, #centercolumn {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.segmentation-left {
    background-color: #e2e3e4;
    width: 100%;
}

#leftcolumn {
     border: 1px #f66511;
     width: 45%;
     background-color: #e2e3e4;
}

#centercolumn {
     width: 10%;
     background-color: #ffffff;
}

#rightcolumn {
     width: 45%;
     background-color: #e2e3e4;
}

.wrapper-promo {
    background-color: #e2e3e4;
    width: 100%;
}

.title-top {
    background-color: #2251a4;
    height: 40px;  
    line-height: 40px;
}


.title-top-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.promo-content {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

h2 {
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:19px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
    margin: 10px 0 -10px 0;
    text-transform:none;
}

    h2.block-title {
        font-size:22px;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform:none;
    }

    .promo-content p {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #232323;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: Peter Rasmussens answer is correct but if you are using the center just as a spacer I would recommend using a `margin` on your divs instead and deleting the center div. You can also use percentages in margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a closing tag for your div:

```
<div class="wrapper-promo">
    <div class="title-top">
        <h2 class="block-title">
            Three states or less</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-content">
        <p>Bid and RFP Notification Only</p>
    <p>Online and email support</p>
        <p><img height="31" src="http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/button_get_started_orange.png" width="112" /></p>
    </div>
</div><!-- This was missing -->
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sukcv46p/27/)

Comment: Yep...  @peterrasmussen beat me to it.  Thats the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know css might be more intuitive for you but in this situation I definitely recommend you to use html `<tables>` just make a table with 1 row and 3 columns.

You can set many things in css to define how the end result will look!

Good luck :)

Comment: This depends what he is doing.  Tables should really only be used for displaying tabular data

Comment: yea,but its not a sin to use them organizing information,even if its not "tabular"

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract `#rightcolumn` and `#centercolumn` out of `#leftcolumn` and have them be sibling divs

```css
#wrapper-segmentation {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
#centercolumn{
    color:black !important;
}
#leftcolumn, #rightcolumn, #centercolumn {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.segmentation-left {
    background-color: #e2e3e4;
    width: 100%;
}

#leftcolumn {
     border: 1px #f66511;
     width: 45%;
     background-color: #e2e3e4;
}

#centercolumn {
     width: 10%;
     background-color: #ffffff;
}

#rightcolumn {
     width: 45%;
     background-color: #e2e3e4;
}

.wrapper-promo {
    background-color: #e2e3e4;
    width: 100%;
}

.title-top {
    background-color: #2251a4;
    height: 40px;  
    line-height: 40px;
}


.title-top-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.promo-content {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

h2 {
 font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size:19px;
    font-weight: bold;
 color:#fff;
    margin: 10px 0 -10px 0;
    text-transform:none;
}

    h2.block-title {
        font-size:22px;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform:none;
    }

    .promo-content p {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #232323;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-segmentation">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
 <div class="wrapper-promo">
  <div class="title-top">
   <h2 class="block-title">
    Three states or less</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="promo-content">
            <p>Bid and RFP Notification Only</p>
        <p>Online and email support</p>
            <p><img height="31" src="http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/button_get_started_orange.png" width="112" /></p>
  </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
    <div id="centercolumn">
        Center
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">
 <div class="wrapper-promo">
  <div class="title-top">
   <h2 class="block-title">
    National or Regional</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="promo-content">
            <p>Bid and RFP Notification Only</p>
        <p>Online and email support</p>
            <p><img height="31" src="http://www.onvia.com/sites/default/files/button_get_started_orange.png" width="112" /></p>
    </div>
```